# Null space of matrix $A$ and column space of transpose matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Show that every vector $v \in\Bbb R^n $ can be written uniquely as $w+u$, where $w$ is in the null space of $A$ and $u$ is in the column space of transpose $A$.

Answer (score 10):

I will provide some thoughts that will help answer this question.

Note that we can use the rank-nullity theorem of a matrix $M\in M_{m \times n}$.

$rk(A)+nul(A)=n$, which means in simpler terms, the number of vectors needed to span the columnspace + the number of vectors needed to span the nullspace is equal to the number of columns.